# Change the background of control in listview when dynamically loading

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using xamarin.forms for my project. I have the listview like below:

```
<ListView x:Name="lst_port" HasUnevenRows="True">
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ViewCell>
                                        <Frame Style="{StaticResource FrmDashboard}" Margin="5">
                                            <StackLayout>
                                                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnPortering_Tapped"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                                                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource LISTTitleLabel}" Text="{Binding PorteringNumber}"></Label>
                                                    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource LISTTitleButton}" Text="{Binding PorteringStatus}" BackgroundColor="#2d964c"></Button>
                                                </Grid>
                                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <Image Style="{StaticResource LISTImageIcon}" Source="note.png"/>
                                                    <Label Style="{StaticResource LISTBodyLabel}" Text="{Binding PorteringAssetNumber}"></Label>
                                                </StackLayout>
                                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <Image Style="{StaticResource LISTImageIcon}" Source="clock.png"/>
                                                    <Label Style="{StaticResource LISTBodyLabel1}" Text="{Binding PorteringDate}"></Label>
                                                    <Image Style="{StaticResource LISTImageIcon}" Source="calender.png"/>
                                                    <Label Style="{StaticResource LISTBodyLabel1}" Text="{Binding PorteringTime}"></Label>
                                                </StackLayout>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </Frame>
                                    </ViewCell>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
```

I assign the value to listview using code behind data table.
The result is like below image:
[image]

Now I want to change the background color of button, when the binding text is "Emergency".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use trigger to achieve this.

Please try below code.

```
<Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource LISTTitleButton}" Text="{Binding PorteringStatus}" BackgroundColor="#2d964c">
    <Button.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding PorteringStatus}" Value="Emergency">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few options:

1. Decide on the button color in the ViewModel that represents a `ListView.Item` - can be done by introducing an additional property in the ViewModel.
2. You can create a [IValueConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters) - which will return the button color according to the input.

For example: `input == "Normal" ? Color.Green : Color.Red`

In both cases you will have to bind the chosen solution to `Button.BackgroundColor` property within the `ListView`.